# Rules for lasso capture?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

In D&D 3.5 suppose a character decides to capture another character, animal or object with a lasso. How would you handle a throw for this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the closest thing would be the net. Like it "lassoing" is probably an exotic weapon (-4 to hit but probably only requires a hit on the foes' touch AC), which entangles the target (-4 to Dex, -2 to hit) and lets you control its movement with a successful opposed Strength check.

Answer (score 13):

The rules for the lasso are in the Book of Exalted Deeds, page 34:

> 1 gold, range increment 10', Exotic weapon
>
> You can target the opponent's arms or legs. Using the lasso to target the legs operates as a standard trip attack, and you can drop the lasso to avoid being tripped in return.
>
> Targeting the opponent's arms, is ranged touch, max range 30'. Target counts as partially entangled, taking -2 on attack rolls and -4 on effective dexterity. Target can still charge or run within the limits of the lasso's range if the holder succeeds on an opposed strength check. DC15 concentration to cast spells while arms are lassoed, DC20 Escape artist as full round action, dc 23 strength check to break as full round action.

Answer (score 1):

If the target was another character, animal, or object held by a character, I would treat it as a grapple attack using the standard rules. If the target was an object, I would treat it as a dexterity skill check. For the difficulty of the check, I would base it from a 15-20 for a stationary medium sized object with the following modifiers: +10 for a moving object, -5 for each category larger or +5 for each category smaller.

Comment: With modifiers for any movement restriction placed on the quarry, maybe? And possibly a "coup-de-grace" auto-succeed when prone/disabled/incapacitated?

Comment: @Logan MacRae Those sound reasonable to me. I always tried to provide a larger than life feel for the game as if the characters were the stars of a movie. To me it was most important to keep the game moving and the players having fun.

Answer (score 0):

Probably as an unmodified attack roll to see if it hits, and then an opposed strength check to see who wins in the ensuing tug of war. It really depends on the situation- lassoing somebody from the back of a horse means you win if you can hit them.

Lassoing is different than a regular grapple, I feel, because of the mechanics. You're not grabbing on to some guy, you're essentially snapping a rope around him and then he falls. In movies, I have yet to see some guy resist being lassoed, but then again, my knowledge of old western movies isn't as good as it once was.